# GridView Paging is not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid in that i am using this code on page init

```
        UpagedList = new PagedListAdapter<User>(UserListGridView);
        UpagedList.MaxRows = ConfigurationService.DefaultPageSize;
        UserListGridView.PageIndexChanged += delegate
        {
            Presenter.FillDataOnDropDown();
        };
       UserListGridView.Sorting += new GridViewSortEventHandler(UserListGridView_Sorting);
       UserListGridView.Sorted += delegate {Presenter.SortChanged(); };
```

my grid code:

```
           <asp:GridView CssClass="Greed" ID="UserListGridView" runat="server" DataSourceID="ListUserDataSource"
              AutoGenerateColumns="false" EmptyDataText="No data found" DataKeyNames="Id" OnSorting="UserListGridView_Sorting" AllowSorting="True"
               PageSize="25" AllowPaging="True" GridLines="None" EnableViewState="false">
                   <Columns></Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

Paging is not working...? what else i need to do for paging.. when i am clicking on 2nd page page is not getting change but data is getting appended in grid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you missing the `OnPageIndexChanging` event in the gridview. Try adding this to your gridview `OnPageIndexChanging="UserListGridViewIndexChanging"`
and in the backend code

```
protected void UserListGridViewIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        UserListGridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        Bind(); // you data bind code
    }
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void UserListGridViewIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    UserListGridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    UserListGridView.DataBind();
    Bind(); // you data bind code is here 
}
```